# [Protractor]How to avoid "console.log" output after validation failure

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am doing e2e testing based on Protractor+selenium+jasmine. I have following code

```
    describe("test google search box", function () {
    function firstPart() {
        console.log("before starting");
        browser.get("http://www.google.com");
        console.log("after running");
    }

    function secondPart() {
        console.log("begin validation");
        var searchBox = element(By.id('kw'));
        **expect(searchBox.getAttribute("id")).toEqual("kw1"); //this is a intentional failure**
        console.log("after validation");

    }


    beforeEach(function () {
        return browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    it("if search box exists", function () {
        var flow = browser.controlFlow();
        protractor.promise.all(flow.execute(firstPart), flow.execute(secondPart));
    });
});
```

I don't want to perform 'console.log("after validation");' because there was a intentional failure in its previous step. How will this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to log only the resolved promises, then place the logging in a promise:

```
function log(message) {
  browser.controlFlow().execute(function(){
    console.log(message);
  });
}

function firstPart() {
    log("before starting");
    browser.get("http://www.google.com");
    log("after running");
}

function secondPart() {
    log("begin validation");
    var searchBox = element(By.id('kw'));
    expect(searchBox.getAttribute("id")).toEqual("kw1"); //this is a intentional failure**
    log("after validation");
}

it("if search box exists", function () {
    firstPart();
    secondPart();
});
```

Output:

```
Started
before starting
after running
begin validation
F

Failures:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is upcoming feature for jasminewd - jasmine that is used in protractor. But currently you can't do it in good way without hacks -

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3234